# Spinner: mark the selected item in the dropdown menu

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

There are many questions around this topic but I don't think any of those answer this question.

I have a Spinner and I'm trying to mark the selected text inside the menu like in this image [image]

I'm seting the Spinner like this:

```
FrequencySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
            R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_info_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    FrequencySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item:*

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

How do I create an adapter that allows it?

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Make a custom adapter.

Comment: @MalithLakshan what do I need to do inside my custom adapter to check the selected text?